# Am Trying To calculate total price of a List of items

Tags: flutter, dart

am making a shopping cart app where I want to calculate the total price of the products present in the cart I made a function for it and tried executing in init state but it's not working

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shop/Models/Database.dart';

class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CartState createState() => _CartState();
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {

  int sum = 0;

  total() {
    studlist.forEach((element) {
      sum = sum + element.price;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    total();
    super.initState();
  }

  final DbStudentManager dbmanager = new DbStudentManager();

  Student cart;
  List<Cart> cartList;
  int updateIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(
          'Cart',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: dbmanager.getStudentList(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              studlist = snapshot.data;
            }
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: studlist == null ? 0 : studlist.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  Student ct = studlist[index];
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(ct.name),
                      subtitle: Text('${ct.price}'),
                      trailing: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                          onPressed: () {
                            dbmanager.deleteStudent(ct.id);
                            setState(() {
                              studlist.remove(index);
                            });
                          }),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          }),
      bottomNavigationBar: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('$sum'),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Text('Check Out'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the error I get:

The method 'forEach' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (Student) => Null)

Comment: Where is studlist initialized?

Comment: where is your `studlist` property initialized?

Comment: Side note: even after `studList` is properly initialized and assigned with an empty list, the UI will not update because you don't call `setState()` after assigning `num` the new value.

Comment: @ Andrey Ozornin i also tried using set state doesnt work

Comment: @cmd_prompter studlist is cartList sorry it was a mistake here

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shop/Models/Database.dart';

class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CartState createState() => _CartState();
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {

  int sum = 0;



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  final DbStudentManager dbmanager = new DbStudentManager();

  Student cart;
  List<Cart> studList=[];
  int updateIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(
          'Cart',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: dbmanager.getStudentList(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              studlist = snapshot.data;
             studlist.forEach((element) {
           setState((){

             sum = sum + element.price;

           });

    });
            }
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: studlist == null ? 0 : studlist.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  Student ct = studlist[index];
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(ct.name),
                      subtitle: Text('${ct.price}'),
                      trailing: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                          onPressed: () {
                            dbmanager.deleteStudent(ct.id);
                            setState(() {
                              studlist.remove(index);
                            });
                          }),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          }),
      bottomNavigationBar: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('$sum'),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Text('Check Out'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running total() function if the data when the data is loaded, not in init. As data is initially empty, running it inside init will cause this error.

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
   studlist = snapshot.data;
   total();
}
```

Full Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shop/Models/Database.dart';

class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CartState createState() => _CartState();
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {

  int sum = 0;

  total() {
    studlist.forEach((element) {
      sum = sum + element.price;
    });
  }

  final DbStudentManager dbmanager = new DbStudentManager();

  Student cart;
  List<Cart> cartList;
  int updateIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(
          'Cart',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: dbmanager.getStudentList(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              studlist = snapshot.data;
              total(); //Run the total() function here
            }
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: studlist == null ? 0 : studlist.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  Student ct = studlist[index];
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(ct.name),
                      subtitle: Text('${ct.price}'),
                      trailing: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                          onPressed: () {
                            dbmanager.deleteStudent(ct.id);
                            setState(() {
                              studlist.remove(index);
                            });
                          }),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          }),
      bottomNavigationBar: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('$sum'),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Text('Check Out'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try this 
If I added Quantity increased totalQty but I have one issue if I removing Item in list
did not decrease. sorry my english not good  

  `total() {

    studlist.forEach((element) {
      if(element.qty!=null){
        totalQty=totalQty+element.qty;
        print(totalQty);
      }
    });
  }
`
```